# Rename autocad in open with list

Tags: windows-7, autocad

I use a Autocad civil 3d 2011, 2012, 2013 and 2014.  Depending on the project I am working on I would want to open a drawing in a specific version.

The "open with" drop down calls them all autocad without the year, if I actually click on "choose program" I get more information

How can I change what it calls them in the "open with" drop down?

Comment: [This](http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-unassociate-remove-or-delete-programs-from-open-with-or-recommended-programs-list/) might help. However, my thoughts on this is that Windows Explorer gets the application's own names; if this is correct, you wouldn't be able to change them.

Answer (score 0):

The application path used when opening DWG files with double-click (i.e. using `AcLauncher.exe`) is found in the registry under:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Autodesk\DwgCommon\shellex\apps\{XXX-...-XXX}:AutoCAD\OpenLaunch
```

You could therefore write a simple batch script to alter this path prior to opening your drawings.